# How to send requests to a web server running inside a docker container inside an AWS EC2 machine from the outside world?

Tags: networking, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-network, docker-container

I have a Python Flask web server running inside a docker container that is running in an AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine. The container is running on a default network setting (docker0). Within the host EC2, I can send requests (Get, Post) to this web server using docker-machine ip (172.x.x.x) and the forwarded ports (3000: 3000) of the host.

```
url: http:// 172.x.x.x:3000 / <api address>
```

How can I send requests **(GET, POST)** to this web server from the outside world? For example from another web server running in another EC2 machine. Or even from the web using my web browser?

- Do I need to get a public **IP Address** for my docker host?
- Is there is **another way** to interact with such web server within another web server running in another EC2?

If you have a solution please explain with as many details as you can for me to understand it.

The only way that I can think of is to write a web server on the main EC2 that listens to the requests and forward them to the appropriate docker container webservers?! But that would be too many redundant codes and I would rather just request to the web server running on the container directly!

Comment: if localhost:3000 works on your instance0, I would next try launching an instance1 in the same security group and try pinging the docker service with instance0-ip:3000. If that works as well, then it is worth debugging your end-to-end service with the load-balancer.

Comment: localhost:3000 works inside my instance. But even the load balancer health check is unable to call my web server. So that shows the other instance will not be able to call my web server in the running in the docker container in the current settings.

Comment: I wouldn't trust localhost:3000 much. try "netstat -a | 3000". It should show that there is a process listening on the port 3000. If not, it means you probably cannot call it from outside as well.

Answer (score 2):

The IP address of the docker is not public. Your EC2 instance usually has a public IP address though. You need an agent listening on a port on your EC2 instance and pass it to your docker/Flask server. Then you would be able to call it from outside using ec2-instance-ip:agent-port.

It's still not a long-term solution as EC2 IPs change when they are stopped. You'd better use a load-balancer or an elastic IP if you want the ip/port to be reliable.

That's right, it makes a lot of redundant code and an extra failure point. That's why it's better to use Amazon's managed docker service (https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/). This way you just launch an EC2 instance which is a docker and has a public IP address. It still allows you to SSH into your EC2 instance and change stuff.